# Filter a SharePoint list via dynamic checkboxes instantly (with C# and/or Ajax)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, sharepoint

I'm currently looking for a way to add a filter function to a list in SharePoint, which filters the lists content via checkbox selection.

This little mockup might help to understand what I'm talking about:

[image: Mockup]

The idea is to have a normal SharePoint custom list on the right and a checkboxlist on the left side, which will be generated dynamically from the content of the list -> One column is a "filter group" and all the field contents are the filter values.

When selecting one or multiple values on the left side, the items in the list should instantly be filtered accordingly (ajax, without reloading the page).
For example in the mockup, selecting "New York" and "Blue" would only show the item "Steve's Car".

You now, like a product filter in almost every online shop and so on.

How can that be achieved? Would be awesome if this could be included in my solution package (which includes other stuff in C#/jQuery already).

I'm new to frontend customization in SharePoint, but I'm sure there's a way :-)

Edit: I'm using SP2016 by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandora!

As i understand it, your first question is how you can dinamically get values for left side filter. I see there two ways: first way, you can build caml query and get items from list; second way, you can use ctx.ListData, which sharepoint initialize by itself and in ctx.ListData.Row (array of items) process items and get unique field values. Note, that ctx.ListData.Row contains only items loaded in list view on the page.

For list filtration you can concat filter link for hash of the page. Example: "?List={ListID}&View={ViewID}&FilterField1=Color-FilterValue1=Blue". Try to filter columns on list and you will see url modification. ListID and ViewId you can retrieve by ctx.listName and ctx.view.

And then pass it in function MyRefreshPageToEx. List will be filtered.

[More list filtration info](https://roykimsharepoint.wordpress.com/2014/05/25/sharepoint-2013-custom-ajax-filters-on-list-view-web-parts/)

```
function FilterList(){
  var tableId = $(".ms-listviewtable").attr("id");
  var filterUrl = "?List={ListID}&View={ViewID}&FilterField1=Color-FilterValue1=Blue";
  MyRefreshPageToEx(tableId, filterUrl, false);
}

function MyRefreshPageToEx(lvTableID, url, bForceSubmit) {
    var tblv = document.getElementById(lvTableID);
    var clvp = CLVPFromCtx(tblv);

    if (clvp != null && clvp.ctx.IsClientRendering) {
        clvp.RefreshPaging(url);
        clvp.ctx.queryString = url;
        if ((typeof clvp.ctx.operationType == "undefined" || clvp.ctx.operationType == SPListOperationType.Default) && Boolean(clvp.ctx.ListData)) {
            var fromPage = clvp.ctx.ListData.FirstRow - 1;
            var toPage = Number(GetUrlKeyValue("PageFirstRow", false, url));

            if (!isNaN(fromPage) && !isNaN(toPage) && fromPage != toPage)
                fromPage < toPage ? (clvp.ctx.operationType = SPListOperationType.PagingRight) : (clvp.ctx.operationType = SPListOperationType.PagingLeft);
        }
    }
    else {
        SubmitFormPost(url, bForceSubmit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Was my advice helpful for you?